# QMediaPlayer para ou pula para próxima ao remover mídia da playlist

Tags: qt, c++11

Como o próprio título diz, o problema encontra-se ao remover uma mídia da playlist, mas precisamente ao remover uma mídia que o índice seja menor do que o da mídia reproduzindo no momento.

Já estou a vários dias pesquisando sobre e não encontrei nada, passou pela mente que ao remover a mídia, automaticamente esta reorganizando os índices, o que não faz sentido parar ou pular para próxima mídia já que esta sendo alterado a playlist e não a mídia atual.

Fiz um teste com o VLC:

1. Ao remover uma mídia com o índice menor do que o da mídia reproduzindo no momento: A mídia atual continuou sendo reproduzida.
2. Ao remover a mídia atual: A reprodução para.

Como posso resolver? Tela do meu projeto:

[image: Tela do meu projeto]

A versão do Qt é a 5.12.5 executando no Ubuntu 19.10 64 bits. Abaixo um [exemplo Mínimo, Completo e Verificável](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):

Player.pro

```
QT       += core gui multimedia

greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets

CONFIG += c++11

DEFINES += QT_DEPRECATED_WARNINGS

SOURCES += \
    main.cpp \
    widget.cpp

HEADERS += \
    widget.h

FORMS += \
    widget.ui
```

main.cpp

```
#include "widget.h"

#include <QApplication>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    Widget w;
    w.show();
    return a.exec();
}
```

widget.h

```
#ifndef WIDGET_H
#define WIDGET_H

#include <QMediaPlayer>
#include <QMediaPlaylist>
#include <QWidget>

QT_BEGIN_NAMESPACE
namespace Ui { class Widget; }
QT_END_NAMESPACE

class Widget : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    Widget(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    ~Widget();

private slots:
    void on_btnPlay_clicked();

    void on_btnNext_clicked();

    void on_btnRemove_clicked();

private:
    Ui::Widget *ui;

    QMediaPlayer    *mPlayer;
    QMediaPlaylist  *mPlaylist;
};
#endif // WIDGET_H
```

widget.cpp

```
#include "widget.h"
#include "ui_widget.h"

Widget::Widget(QWidget *parent)
    : QWidget(parent)
    , ui(new Ui::Widget)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    mPlayer     = new QMediaPlayer(this);
    mPlaylist   = new QMediaPlaylist(mPlayer);
    mPlaylist->setPlaybackMode(QMediaPlaylist::Loop);
    mPlaylist->addMedia(QUrl::fromLocalFile("/home/wmsouza/Música/LINKIN PARK - IN THE END.mp3"));
    mPlaylist->addMedia(QUrl::fromLocalFile("/home/wmsouza/Música/LINKIN PARK - NUMB.mp3"));
    mPlaylist->addMedia(QUrl::fromLocalFile("/home/wmsouza/Música/METALLICA - FADE TO BLACK.mp3"));
    mPlaylist->addMedia(QUrl::fromLocalFile("/home/wmsouza/Música/METALLICA - NOTHING ELSE MATTERS.mp3"));

    mPlayer->setPlaylist(mPlaylist);
}

Widget::~Widget()
{
    delete ui;
}


void Widget::on_btnPlay_clicked()
{
    mPlayer->play();
}

void Widget::on_btnNext_clicked()
{
    mPlayer->playlist()->next();
}

void Widget::on_btnRemove_clicked()
{
    mPlaylist->removeMedia(ui->mediaIndex->text().toInt());
}
```

widget.ui

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>Widget</class>
 <widget class="QWidget" name="Widget">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>220</width>
    <height>102</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>Widget</string>
  </property>
  <layout class="QGridLayout" name="gridLayout">
   <item row="0" column="0">
    <widget class="QPushButton" name="btnPlay">
     <property name="text">
      <string>PLAY</string>
     </property>
    </widget>
   </item>
   <item row="0" column="2">
    <widget class="QPushButton" name="btnNext">
     <property name="text">
      <string>PRÓXIMA</string>
     </property>
    </widget>
   </item>
   <item row="1" column="2">
    <widget class="QPushButton" name="btnRemove">
     <property name="text">
      <string>REMOVER</string>
     </property>
    </widget>
   </item>
   <item row="1" column="0">
    <widget class="QLineEdit" name="mediaIndex"/>
   </item>
  </layout>
 </widget>
 <resources/>
 <connections/>
</ui>
```

Comment: Não consegui testar ainda, mas chegou a tentar executar o next antes de remover? Algo como `void Widget::on_btnRemove_clicked()
{   on_btnNext_clicked();
    mPlaylist->removeMedia(ui->mediaIndex->text().toInt());
}`? Só quero lembra-lo que ao usar uma outra "origem" para os index da playlist, você tem que lembra de ajustar os indices, por exemplo se estiver usando um `QTableWidget` você tem que tomar cuidado com o index (creio que já o fez, só estou falando mesmo por "paz de espirito")

Comment: Executar o next antes não resolve, o player para ou pula do mesmo jeito.. em relação a ajustar os índices ta tudo certo.

Comment: Pensei que ele não parava a musica que foi removida e "continuava", mas pelo seu ultimo comentário parece que está ocorrendo outra coisa.